# Vector planes - equation of the plane

Tags: vectors

What is the equation of the plane that passes through the points $A(1,2,3)$ and $B(3,2,1)$ and is orthogonal to the plane $4x-y+2z=7$?

I do not know how to start. Am I searching for the intersection of the planes first?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The plane you're looking for should include a vector orthogonal to the plane $4x-y+2z=7$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The vector form of the equation of a plane is
$$\vec{x}=\vec{P}+t\vec{d}_1+u\vec{d}_2$$

where $\vec{P}$ is a point on the plane, $\vec{d}_1,\vec{d}_2$ are two direction vectors of the plane. You can find one direction vector of the plane using the two given points. Another direction vector is the normal vector of the orthogonal plane.

Answer (score 1):

To get the normal $n$ to the plane you require, which must be perpendicular both to $AB$ and the given plane, calculate the cross-product of $AB$ and $4i-j+2k$.

Then use the formula for the plane in scalar product form i.e. $r*n=a*n$ with $a$ as the position vector of either $A$ or of $B$